# Ant Design Table - Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I implemented a realtime data grid table using React Redux and SignalR. After the first item is added to table/the first dispatch happens, the following console error is logged:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
> Check the render method of `Body`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.

I understand what the issue is but how do I fix it?

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Table } from "antd";
import { HubConnectionState } from "redux-signalr";
import hubConnection from "../store/middlewares/signalr/signalrSlice";
import { Stock, addStock } from "../store/reducers/stockSlice";
import { RootState } from "../store";

const DataGrid = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const stocks = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.stock.stocks);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hubConnection.state !== HubConnectionState.Connected) {
      hubConnection
        .start()
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Started connection via SignalR");

          hubConnection.stream("GetStockTickerStream").subscribe({
            next: async (item: Stock) => {
              console.log(item);
              dispatch(addStock(item)); // Dispatch addStock action to update Redux store
            },
            complete: () => {
              console.log("Completed");
            },
            error: (err) => {
              console.error(err);
            },
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.error(`Faulted: ${err.toString()}`));
    }
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <Table dataSource={stocks}>
      <Table.Column title="Symbol" dataIndex="symbol" key="symbol" />
      <Table.Column title="Price" dataIndex="price" key="price" />
    </Table>
  );
};

export default DataGrid;
```

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export type Stock = Readonly<{
  id: number;
  symbol: string;
  price: number;
}>;

export type StockState = Readonly<{
  stocks: Stock[];
}>;

const initialState: StockState = {
  stocks: [],
};

const stockSlice = createSlice({
  name: "stock",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    addStock: (state, action: PayloadAction<Stock>) => {
      state.stocks = [action.payload];
    },
  },
});

export const { addStock } = stockSlice.actions;

export default stockSlice.reducer;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key property is expected in the data

```
const stocks = [
  {
    key: '1', // some key in the data
    title: 'John Brown',
    symbol: 'x,
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    title: 'John Brown',
    symbol: 'x,
  },
] 

return (
    <Table dataSource={stocks}>
      <Table.Column title="Symbol" dataIndex="symbol" key="symbol" />
      <Table.Column title="Price" dataIndex="price" key="price" />
    </Table>
  );
```

or you can pass a `rowKey` prop of type `function(record): string` as given in the [api](https://ant.design/components/table#api)

```
return (
    <Table 
       dataSource={stocks}
       rowKey={(record) => record.key} // some function that return a unique key 
    >
      <Table.Column title="Symbol" dataIndex="symbol" key="symbol" />
      <Table.Column title="Price" dataIndex="price" key="price" />
    </Table>
  );
```

Add or edit a row

```
 // assuming PayloadAction return a single object
 addEditStock: (state, action: PayloadAction<Stock>) => {
      const updatedList = state.stocks?.map(stock => {

         if (stock.id === PayloadAction?.id) {
           // Create a *new* object with changes
           return { ...stock, ...PayloadAction };
         } else {
            // No changes
           return stock;
         }

      });

      state.stocks = updatedList ?? [];
 },
```

beta docs about [updating array in React](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#updating-objects-inside-arrays)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I added `id` to the `Stock` type, but it is kinda the same object with the same ID which is being updated and SignalR just updates that item.

Comment: one way to handle it could be to update update the existing row with the same id, but if you need duplicate rown then include a timestamp unique id

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is not the key of your columns, but the key of your rows. Can you show the structure of your datasource?
In the antd documentation, the dataSource is supposed to look like this:

```
const dataSource = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'Mike',
    age: 32,
    address: '10 Downing Street',
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'John',
    age: 42,
    address: '10 Downing Street',
  },
];
```

Make sure that each row has its own key.

---

Regarding your edit:
Try to format your row data, so that it looks like this:

```
{
key: "1",
symbol: "TESLA",
price: 65.48
},
{
key: "2",
symbol: "TESLA",
price: 94.61
}
```

Comment: Edited my question with the `Stock` type

Comment: I have edited my answer.
Try to rename "id" to "key", and make sure its unique and of type "string", for every data entry. Or let "id" as it is, and add another property called "key" for every data entry. Make sure its unique for every data entry.

Comment: I cannot make it unique. Everytime SignalR pushes/dispatches a new `Stock` item, it technically replaces the previous one. If there were 20 items, SignalR would push the new list everytime and you have to replace the previous records with the new ones.

Comment: Think of `hubConnection` as a websocket and everytime it pushes a new `Stock[]` item, `dispatch(addStock(item))` replaces the previous list with the new list that has just arrived (even tho it's a list, it currently consists of one item with id = 1). That's probably the issue, the fact that I'm replacing the table dataSource with the same item over and over again but different `price` value as it updates.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by  Azzy and ActionReacto you are missing the key prop, but the problem is how to add it using selector?, so here is the way you can do it

```
const stocks = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.stock.stocks.map(t:any,index:number)=>({key:index,...t}));`
```

here instead of index ,you can use any other unique value as key like stock.id.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated the `Stock` model, so it now includes `id`. What is it supposed to be right now?

Comment: that should fix the error, i will suggest you to share codesandbox or codepane to demonstrate the issue ,this will help more

Comment: I'm not sure how to simulate it in codesandbox. Think of `hubConnection` as a websocket and everytime it pushes a new `Stock` item, `dispatch(addStock(item))` replaces the previous list with the new list that just arrived (even tho it's a list, it currently consists of one item with id = 1). That's probably the issue, the fact that I'm replacing the table dataSource with the same item over and over again but different `price` value as it updates.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're passing key as a prop to a React component class and the `key` prop is reserved for loop-generated (e.g. `map()`) components. React is telling you that every component needs to have a unique key. This has nothing to do with the key prop in your column definition for antd. So instead of passing the key as a prop, try this:

```js
  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Symbol",
      dataIndex: "symbol",
      key: "symbol",
    },
    {
      title: "Price",
      dataIndex: "price",
      key: "price",
    },
  ];

  return <Table dataSource={stocks} columns={columns} />;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to have fixed it. Maybe I'm supposed to use the `id` somehow which I just added to the `Stock` model?